# DOMdocument: How to change id and name attribute when use cloneNode?

Tags: php, dom

I'm using DOMdocument to create forms. 
To add more input box in the fieldset, I use this:

```
$fieldset->appendChild ( $textinput->cloneNode());
```

I would like to learn how to change the id and name of the cloned input box. for example, the first input box is id = "box", name="box-input", then, in the clone, I want it be id="box-2", name = "box-input-2". Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone it first, change the attributes and append it:

```
$clone = $textinput->cloneNode();
$clone->setAttribute('id', '...');
$clone->setAttribute('name', '...');
$fieldset->appendChild($clone);
```